# Viewing group as a Vector space over $Z_p$

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces

I have following problem. Let $G$ be finite and have more than 1 element. If group of automorphisms of $G$ acts transitively on $G \setminus {e}$ then G is isomorphic to $(Z_p)^n$ for some prime number $p$.

It can be shown that $G$ is abelian p-group and every non-identity element has order $p$ for some prime number $p$.

How this implies that we can view G as Vector space over $Z_p$? How is even scalar multiplication possible? I mean elements of groups can be something like rotations, reflections (I know D_n is not abelian and therefore we don't consider it but I presume that there are some groups which we consider and have elements that are not compatible with numbers).

Why is it necessary that $p$ is prime?

Comment: Your second paragraph already shows that $G$ is isomorphic as a group to $(\Bbb Z_p)^n$. It just remains to notice that multiplication by elements of $\Bbb Z_p$ does indeed provide a valid scalar multiplication that makes $G$ a vector space. Basically this is the same calculation that $\Bbb Z_p$ is a ring that is a field, and just noting that the elements in the $n$-tuple each behave in this way. As for why $p$ must be prime, there are lots of things that go wrong, but from the initial problem: does the group of automorphisms of $\Bbb Z_4$ act transitively on $\Bbb Z_4\setminus\{0\}$?

Comment: "How is even scalar multiplication possible?"  You know how to multiply an element by an integer (it's repeated addition).  If the order of the element is $p$, then multiplying it by $k$ is the same as multiplying it by $k + p$, or by $k + 2p$, or ....